# Hot to take a text-box value for calculate date difference?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm new to JavaScript and trying calculate date difference. I'm trying to get one `date` from value of `text-box` and another `date` from `date-picker`. But while calculating the difference it gives me wrong answer.

**here is my code:**

```
$('#ELEdatepicker1').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
startDate: new Date(),
todayHighlight: true,
}).change(function(){
getELEdifference($(this));
});
// var ELEexpDate = document.getElementById('#ELEtextDate').value;
var ELEexpDate = document.getElementById('#ELEtextDate');
function getELEdifference($this)
{
if($this.datepicker("getDate") != null)
{
var ELEcertDiff= ELEexpDate - $this.datepicker("getDate");    
var result = Math.round(ELEcertDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1);
if(result == 1095 || result == 1825 || result == 3652)
{
document.getElementById("ELEcertDiff").value = result;
} else {
alert('Are you sure ?');
document.getElementById("ELEcertDiff").value = result;
}
}
}
```

This is my **jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/2trf5a8y/32/

I'm confused where I'm making a mistake. Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two issues in your code. The line `document.getElementById('#ELEtextDate')` will not give the value of the text box. You have to change any one of like.

```
document.getElementById('ELEtextDate').value
```

or

```
$('#ELEtextDate').val()
```

Now the second issue is you can't directly subtract the non date values, means you have to convert your value into the date format, then you can subtract. The line

```
 var ELEcertDiff= ELEexpDate - $this.datepicker("getDate");
```

Should change to

```
 var ELEcertDiff= new Date(ELEexpDate) - $this.datepicker("getDate");
```

[**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2trf5a8y/66/)

The same I have implemented in the following **Snippet**

```js
$('#ELEdatepicker1').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
startDate: new Date(),
todayHighlight: true,
}).change(function(){
getELEdifference($(this));
});
// var ELEexpDate = document.getElementById('#ELEtextDate').value;
var ELEexpDate = document.getElementById('ELEtextDate').value;
function getELEdifference($this)
{
if($this.datepicker("getDate") != null)
{
var ELEcertDiff= new Date(ELEexpDate) - $this.datepicker("getDate");
var result = Math.round(ELEcertDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1);
if(result == 1095 || result == 1825 || result == 3652)
{
document.getElementById("ELEcertDiff").value = result;
} else {
alert('Are you sure ?');
document.getElementById("ELEcertDiff").value = result;
}
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date:<input type="text" id="ELEdatepicker1"><br><br>
Diff:<input type="text" id="ELEcertDiff"><br><br>
Days:<input type="text" id="ELEtextDate" value="01/01/2012"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove # when you getElementById, and get its value. After you have this value you need to convert it into Date using new Date(..parameters) and then you can subtract with date from datepicker. You will have milliseconds difference between both. You can divide by 1000 for secs, or again by 60 for minutes and so on.

`document.getElementById('ELEtextDate').value;`